# ionic menu bar disappears on android

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I have difficulties using Ionic on Android.
This is is my screen showing Details of a training. 
[image]

As you can see, there is a menu bar at the top, saying "Training Detail" and a back button. However, when I click on an option button of the first item "Laufband" a detail page is shown with information of that exercise. 
[image]

As you can see, the menu bar is missing. Here is what it looks like on iOS (everything looks great) and the code of that page:
[image]

```
<ion-view view-title="{{exerciseInfo.name}}">
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button  ng-click="goBack()" class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-dark">
      Zurück
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding">

    <div ng-bind-html="exerciseInfo.info"></div>
    <div ng-if="!exerciseInfo.info">
      Keine Info vorhanden!
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I don't think you should see screenshotes with *Run bitch* ;)

Comment: It would be nice if you could create a plunker with your code.